# How to get clicked item in textbox from dropdown listview javafx 8?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-8

I am trying to get clicked value in my textbox, i have added listener but not getting the adjact output. Please suggest me how to do.

```
ObservableList<String> data5 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(smooth);
listView.setItems(data5);

listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
      new ChangeListener<String>() {
              public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, 
                    String old_val, String new_val) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("********"+new_val);

                        txtCustomerName.textProperty();
                        txtCustomerName.setText(new_val);
                    }
        });
```

[image]

Comment: can u please explain more..it is not clear what you exactly want

Comment: r u trying to get the value of focused (where your mouse cursor shows) text box? what does the list data5 contains. What is listView?

Comment: Sir, when user click any item like Apple the list should disappear and value should be in textbox.

Comment: the complete aim is to appear list and disappear list when user select an Item. Please suggest me how to do. do i need to add any event?

Comment: @Jayaprasad sir, data5 contain value from database and listView is list showing that data5 value..all thing is going well but could not appear and dissapear that list when user click an Item. Finally i want google search like feature in my textbox

Comment: I not getting the UI design? Is company Name field a auto populated combo box, which displays a drop down list on typing?

Comment: no sir i forcly placed a listview there for testing. that list view contain related value typed in texbox. that should disappear when user click on it and appear when user click on textbox.... i am sorry if i am not clear

Comment: Ok.. use combo box instead of textbox with list view. You can hide the arrow button in the combo box, so that it looks like a textbox. Add a selection listener to combobox and populate rest of the fields based on selection.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379865/how-to-hide-the-down-arrow-button-on-a-combobox-in-javafx

Comment: @Jayaprasad sir how to do in my case, i just want to appear that listview when user click on txtbox and hide it. please suggest me how to do that, i am new to this... looking for urgent help

Comment: @user3675069 are you able to achieve your design with textbox and listview? Your boss still sticks to textbox and listview?

Answer (score 3):

```
public class FillForm extends Application {

    Text addressOne;
    Text addressTwo;
    Text mobileOne;
    Text email;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Label companyNameLbl = new Label("Company Name");
        ComboBox<String> companyName = new ComboBox<String>();
        companyName.setEditable(true);

        populateCompanyName(companyName);
        addComboListener(companyName);

        HBox companyHbox = new HBox(25);
        companyHbox.getChildren().addAll(companyNameLbl, companyName);

        Label addressOneLbl = new Label("Address One");
        addressOne = new Text();

        HBox addressOneHbox = new HBox();
        addressOneHbox.getChildren().addAll(addressOneLbl, addressOne);

        Label addressTwoLbl = new Label("Address two");
        addressTwo = new Text();

        HBox addressTwoHbox = new HBox();
        addressTwoHbox.getChildren().addAll(addressTwoLbl, addressTwo);

        Label mobileLbl = new Label("Company Name");
        mobileOne = new Text();

        HBox mobileHbox = new HBox();
        mobileHbox.getChildren().addAll(mobileLbl, mobileOne);

        Label emailLbl = new Label("Company Name");
        email = new Text();

        HBox emailHbox = new HBox();
        emailHbox.getChildren().addAll(emailLbl, email);

        VBox form = new VBox(20);
        form.getChildren().addAll(companyHbox, addressOneHbox, addressTwoHbox,
                mobileHbox, emailHbox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(form);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/comboStyles.css");
        stage.show();
    }

    private void addComboListener(final ComboBox<String> combo) {

        combo.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                if (combo.getValue().equals("Apple")) {
                    addressOne.setText("\t Apple address one");
                    addressTwo.setText("\t Apple address two");
                    mobileOne.setText("\t Apple mobile number");
                    email.setText("\t Apple email");
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public void populateCompanyName(ComboBox<String> combo) {
        combo.getItems().add("Intel");
        combo.getItems().add("Apple");
        combo.getItems().add("Microsoft");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**comboStyles.css**

```
.combo-box .arrow, .combo-box .arrow-button{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

**output:**

[image]

[image]

I have made a rough example without using proper layouts. You use the appropriate layout for your UI. Populate the combobox with your data5 list and in the action listener of the combo box check for the selected value and fill other fields.

**Update**

Since you have to use only text box as your company said, the below links guide you in that. You have to create a customized text box by extending the Text class of Javafx.

https://github.com/privatejava/javafx-autocomplete-field

http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/07/04/autofill-textbox-with-filtermode-in-javafx-2-0-custom-control/

**Autofill text field jars:**

https://code.google.com/p/jfx-autocomplete-textfield/

Comment: company denyed to use combobox... they suggested to use.. textbox only. In my case all thing is going well, just suggest me how to appear and disappear that listview in relation to texbox click.

Comment: interesting..!! Not allowed to use a class in JavaFx. !!! let me think of the design before i comment here.. But without combo it will be difficult and i would say that your company is not using features which the framework provides to make your work easier.

Comment: Sir, as inside pic i posted in question, you may see the how texbox and listview are smoothly connected. When user type any word , all related data from database appear in listview, so that is going well. but i failed to appear that listview and dissappear it in relation to texbox. I implemented your combobox and work sucessfully but boss told me..forget COMBOBOX  (welkinakash5 gmail)

Comment: @user3675069  Thats fine. But in your UI, the connection between listview and textbox is not connected properly. User will not understand that the selection he is going to make in list view will be the value of text box. As far as i am concerned, this is not a good design. Any how do as boss said for your job safety :) . Consider my updated answer where you can see an example which suits your scenario of using text box and forgetting combobox.

Comment: I think if I were told I needed to provide a combination of a text field and a list view, which is what a ComboBox is, but that I wasn't allowed to use a ComboBox, I would probably tell them to find a different developer ;).