# JavaFX: Hide ComBox arrow

Tags: javafx, combobox

I am trying to hide the `ComboBox` arrow using the method in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379865/how-to-hide-the-down-arrow-button-on-a-combobox-in-javafx), but for some reason I get this:
[image]

Comment: that's look like a TextField, which modification have you done?

Comment: I added the css described in the link

Comment: The solution works for me, try to post your own code, the error probably comes from there !

Comment: @Ayoub.A FYI the solution does NOT work for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.combo-box, .arrow, .arrow-button{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

to get rid of all other colours appearing (focused: border-color/border-glow and unfocused: shadow) add .text-field

```
.combo-box, .arrow, .arrow-button, .text-field{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

be aware that every text-field/arrow/arrow-button will be affected. To get around this, you need to add your css-style-sheet to the node itself

```
your-combo-box-node.getStylesheets().add(Main.class.getResource("styles.css").toExternalForm());
```

If you need more flexibility with the styling of the individual parts of the node itself, split up the css-code-line

```
.combo-box{ -fx- ... }
.arrow{ -fx- ... }
.arrow-button{ -fx- ... }
.text-field{ -fx- ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really old post but just an update if anybody need it. If you want to style just one combo box you can do it in two other ways. First to define id of the combo in Css

```
#idOfTheComboBox>  .arrow-button > .arrow {
   -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
#idOfTheComboBox>  .arrow-button {
   -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

or with class

```
.your-class >  .arrow-button > .arrow {
   -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.your-class >  .arrow-button {
   -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```